# Google Fit REST API dataSource datasets return no Points

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve [points](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/datasets) from a dataSource dataset using the Google Fit REST API

As explained in another StackOverflow post I've first made this API call to get a list of dataSources:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources
```

And then using the ID of a dataSource supplied in the response I make this query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.distance.delta:com.google.android.gms:asus:Nexus 7:f0e3ca13:/datasets/000000-1419867599
```

Which according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/datasets/get) should return a Users.dataSources.datasets resource that includes points. However this is all I get:

```
{
  "minStartTimeNs": "0", 
  "maxEndTimeNs": "1419867599", 
  "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.distance.delta:com.google.android.gms:asus:Nexus 7:f0e3ca13:"
}
```

I've tried other dataSource ID's from the first API call and the result is the same. What am I doing wrong, how do I get dataPoints returned in the response ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is: `$StartTime*1000000000;`

And convert in string using this function: http://php.net/manual/es/function.floatval.php#106367

Comment: You're correct the issue was that the endtime was not in nanoseconds. This call works fine:

`https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.distance.delta:com.google.android.gms:asus:Nexus 7:f0e3ca13:/datasets/000000-1420845034000000000`